# Fourier transform of a function with large support concentrates on a short segment

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $g(x)$ be smooth and compactly supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$. I know the Fourier transform $\hat{g}(y)$ concentrates on a short segment near $y=0$ if the support is big. However, I'd like to see how "short" this segment is in terms of $g(x)$ and the length of supp $g$.

I got some rough bounds on $\hat{g}(y)$ with some extra conditions such as the growth of $g^{(j)}$ using integration by parts but I don't see how to show this in general. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Well, that's more of an informal statement than an exact fact. You always have the example of the Gaussian $e^{-|x|^2}$, whose Fourier transform is essentially itself, up to irrelevant constants. The Gaussian has a big support; all of $\mathbb R^n$, and its Fourier transform also has a big support.

Comment: The exact statement is the *uncertainty principle*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle

Comment: I didn't mean the Fourier transform has a short support by 'concentrates on a short segment'. I meant that more spread out $g(y)$, faster $\hat{g} (y)$ decays as you move away from $y=0$, essentially the first sentence of what you linked here. So in case of the Gaussian, I know $\hat{g}(y)\ll e^{-y^2}$ and I want bounds like this in terms of $g(y)$ and the support of $g$ for general smooth functions.

Comment: I don't think you can get pointwise bounds, but only integral ones. I can be wrong though. It is an interesting question.